# Is a question about drush still out of scope?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45737/how-to-get-backtrace-information-for-php-errors-in-drush) about drush was closed in 2013 for being out of scope of DA SA.

I wonder, is that policy still in effect? Are questions about drush and drush alone not within the scope?

I would note that, in an answer for the closed question, there is a link to a drush feature request, wherein  one of the [drush devs refers users to drupal.stackexchange](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush/issues/1804600#comment-7850309) for drush support.

Comment: Probably to set the expectation from the drush (and other products) devs referring to this site, please refer to [Can I support my product on this site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)

Answer (score 4):

That question was closed because it was debugging drush, which is a general PHP issue.  It also turned into a feature request.

Questions about drush, drupal console, and Drupal tooling are welcome here, as long as the question is Drupal specific.

On-topic: How do can I use `drush sql-dump` with a bastion SSH connection.

Off-topic: How do I setup Docker for a Drupal site?